# How to sort a nested dictionary based on sum of inner values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to sort a nested dictionary in descending order.
Here is my dictionary:

```
mydict = {'first': {1:10,3:3},'second' : {7:5}, 'thrid': {4:2,5:4}}
```

and the wanted result is

```
mydict = {'first':{1:10,3:3}, 'third': {4:2,5:4}, 'second' : {7:5}}
```

Since the first's inner value's sum is 13, the third is 6, and the second is 5.
And I would like to save its keys in the same order in a list

```
mylist = {1,3,4,7,5}
```

Here is what I've tried so far

```
for out_key, out_value in d.items():
  for key,value in sorted(out_value,key=lambda i:sum(i[1]),reverse=True):
      answer.append(key)
```

This nexted for loop gives me an error saying

```
'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I assume that because the key is not string.
How should I fix the nested for loop ?
Or is there a better way to sort a nested dictionary based on the sum of inner values?

Thank you

Comment: In your example result, where does `5:5` in `second` and `7:4` in `thrid` come from?

Comment: Oh wait, I made a mistake there, I'll edit it! @LoicRW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost correct. You applied `sorted` on `values` instead you need to use `d.items()`. You can use the `key` parameter in `sorted` to tell it to sort by the sum of the values.

```py
mydict = {'first': {1:10,3:3},'second' : {7:5}, 'thrid': {4:2,5:4}}

output = dict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: sum(x[1].values()), reverse=True))

print(output)
```

```
{'first': {1: 10, 3: 3}, 'thrid': {4: 2, 5: 4}, 'second': {7: 5}}
```

Comment: I came up with the same code. You're just missing the resulting list: `result = [key for e in output.values() for key in e]`. And of course one needs a current version of Python because preserving the order of the entries wasn't guaranteed before Python 3.7.

Comment: Thank you! that helped a lot :)